# How to set Grid row and column positions programmatically

Tags: wpf, gridview

I have two Grids inside a Stackpanel.
The first grid is named as GridX.
Initially, inside the grid, there is a 2D array of Textboxes(RowDefs/ColumnDefs).
The TextBox definition in XAML is

```
<TextBox x:Name="A1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

I want to add a **TextBlock** programmatically in the same position as part of GridX.

The effect must be like this

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="10" FontSize="8"/>
```

How to add this.
I have tried this:

```
TextBlock tblock = new TextBlock();
GridX.SetColumn(tblock, cIndex);
GridX.SetRow(tblock, rIndex);
```

But failed.

Again I tried this:

```
int rIndex = Grid.GetRow(txtBox);
int cIndex = Grid.GetColumn(txtBox);                               

TextBlock tblock = new TextBlock();
tblock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
tblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
tblock.FontSize = 8;
tblock.Text = rc[i, j - 1];

Grid.SetColumn(tblock, cIndex);
Grid.SetRow(tblock, rIndex);

txtBox.MaxLength = 1;
```

Now the problem is that TextBlock is not visible. TextBox hides it.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Code got updated.Now the problem is visibility of textblock

Answer (score 207, accepted):

For attached properties you can either call SetValue on the object for which you want to assign the value:

```
tblock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 4);
```

Or call the static Set method (not as an instance method like you tried) for the property on the owner type, in this case SetRow:

```
Grid.SetRow(tblock, 4);
```

Comment: SetRow worked while SetValue did not: it was leaving row as is (zero in my case)

Comment: You need to ensure that TextBlock instance is part of the Grid instance, you can do this:
mygrid.Children.Add(myTextBlock);

Comment: Don´t forget use a dispatcher when you need to execute the change on runtime. That was my case.

Answer (score 38):

Here is an example which might help someone:

```
Grid test = new Grid();
test.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
test.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
test.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
test.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
test.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

Label t1 = new Label();
t1.Content = "Test1";
Label t2 = new Label();
t2.Content = "Test2";
Label t3 = new Label();
t3.Content = "Test3";
Label t4 = new Label();
t4.Content = "Test4";
Label t5 = new Label();
t5.Content = "Test5";
Label t6 = new Label();
t6.Content = "Test6";

Grid.SetColumn(t1, 0);
Grid.SetRow(t1, 0);
test.Children.Add(t1);

Grid.SetColumn(t2, 1);
Grid.SetRow(t2, 0);
test.Children.Add(t2);

Grid.SetColumn(t3, 0);
Grid.SetRow(t3, 1);
test.Children.Add(t3);

Grid.SetColumn(t4, 1);
Grid.SetRow(t4, 1);
test.Children.Add(t4);

Grid.SetColumn(t5, 0);
Grid.SetRow(t5, 2);
test.Children.Add(t5);

Grid.SetColumn(t6, 1);
Grid.SetRow(t6, 2);
test.Children.Add(t6);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    test.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

    Label t1 = new Label();
    t1.Content = "Test" + i;

    Grid.SetColumn(t1, i);
    Grid.SetRow(t1, 0);
    test.Children.Add(t1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
                Grid grid = new Grid(); //Define the grid
                for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) //Add 36 rows
                {
                    ColumnDefinition columna = new ColumnDefinition()
                    {
                        Name = "Col_" + i,
                        Width = new GridLength(32.5),
                    };
                    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columna);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) //Add 36 columns
                {
                    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                    row.Height = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Pixel);
                    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 36; j++)
                    {
                        Label t1 = new Label()
                        {
                            FontSize = 10,
                            FontFamily = new FontFamily("consolas"),
                            FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold,
                            BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray,
                            BorderThickness = new Thickness(2),
                            HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                        };
                        Grid.SetRow(t1, i);
                        Grid.SetColumn(t1, j);
                        grid.Children.Add(t1); //Add the Label Control to the Grid created
                    }
                }
```