# Edit children placement in rows and columns directly from the object definition

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following object:

```
new Grid {
    RowDefinitions =
    {
        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
    },
    ColumnDefinitions =
    {
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) },    
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }
    },
    Children =
    {
        new Label { Text = "TRIP #5", FontFamily = Device.OnPlatform(null, "latoblack.ttf#Lato Black", null), FontSize = 16, TextColor = Color.White, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10) },
        new Label { Text = "Started 24/07/2017", FontFamily = Device.OnPlatform(null, "latolight.ttf#Lato Light", null), FontSize = 16, TextColor = Color.White, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start },
        new Label { Text = "Is currently in progress", FontFamily = Device.OnPlatform(null, "latolight.ttf#Lato Light", null), FontSize = 16, TextColor = Color.White, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start }
    }
}
```

I want to place the labels in positions (0,0), (0,1), (1,1) without having to use  Children.Add. More specifically, I want to set the position of the labels to the positions that I mentioned directly from the object definition. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: dup:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745594/how-to-set-grid-row-and-column-positions-programmatically

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I am trying to set the position without having to use any function outside the Grid object.

Comment: what's the benefit then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Grid` static methods `Grid.SetRow, Grid.SetColumn` etc. like so:

```
        var label = new Label { Text = "TRIP #5", FontSize = 16, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10) };
        var grid = new Grid {
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
            },
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) },    
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }
            },
            Children =
            {
                label,
            }
        };

        grid.Padding = new Thickness(0,20,0,0);


        Grid.SetRow(label, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(label,2);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(label, 3);

        this.Content = grid;
```

Comment: Isn't there any way that I can set the row/column position from inside the Grid object?

Comment: Well, another way is  `myGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Row 1" }, 0, 0);` but that is clearly what you do not want to use :)