# C# Change Image Column and Row

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a question. I added an Image to my Grid, but now I want to change the row of the image from 0 to 2. I already gave my image a name: "imgColorPicker" How can I do this using C#?

Here is my code:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="Color_Picker" x:Name="imgColorPicker"/>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove it then re-add it in the correct cell

```
MainGrid.Children.Remove(imgColorPicker);
MainGrid.Children.Add(imgColorPicker, col, row);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any condition to change the row index? If there is, you can change it with a trigger or value converter. You can achive that in the code behind too, check this [how-to-set-grid-row-and-column-positions-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745594/how-to-set-grid-row-and-column-positions-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

The following should solve your problem:

```
Grid.SetRow(imgColorPicker, 2);
```